# Запятая перед и/или

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, или

В ГОСТе написано: Сыр - молочный или составной молочный продукт, изготовляемый из молока (,) и/или молочных продуктов, и/или побочных продуктов переработки молока с использованием или без использования специальных заквасок...

Нужна ли запятая перед первым и/или? В ГОСТе ее нет. Согласно правилу, тут получается три однородных, связанных повторяющимся союзом и/или: "из молока", и/или "из молочных продуктов", и/или "из побочных продуктов". Согласно Д. Э. Розенталю нужно ставить перед каждым союзом и запятую. Схема О, и/или О, и/или О. Правильно ли?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По Ррозенталю - да

5. Если число однородных членов больше двух, а союз повторяется перед каждым из них, кроме первого, то запятая ставится между ними всеми, например: А вокруг были дым, и бой, и смерть (Горбатов); Иные хозяева вырастили уже вишни, или сирень, или жасмин (Фадеев); Только мальвы, да ноготки, да крученый паныч цвели кое-где по дорогам (В. Панова).

http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/43.htm
(Розенталь Д.Э., Джанджакова Е.В., Кабанова Н.П. 
СПРАВОЧНИК ПО ПРАВОПИСАНИЮ, ПРОИЗНОШЕНИЮ, ЛИТЕРАТУРНОМУ РЕДАКТИРОВАНИЮ
§87. Однородные члены, соединенные повторяющимися союзами)

Но, честно говоря, именно этот момент всегда вызывал вопросы в отношении возможности иной трактовки. Ведь тут есть лазейка в виде распадающихся на группы членов. Если считать "молоко и молочные продукты" одной группой, противопоставляемой остальным членам, то отсутствие запятой оправдано. Не уверен, правда, что такая трактовка может иметь место в нашем случае даже гипотетически. Поэтому лучше запятую сохранить.

Comment: А почему тогда ставится запятая перед и/или во втором случае, если установлено, что "молоко и молочные продукты" -- одна группа? Ведь выходит же два однородных члена, или у групп какие-то особые свойства в этом отношении?

Comment: @PersonaNonGrata В этом случае. естественно, и второй запятой не требуется. Но у нас эта трактовка малореальна сама по себе.